# Saving HABTM with extra fields?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to save an order, and the products in the order.

The order is being saved, but the products are not.

I have an `orders` table and a `products` table and a `orders_products` table.

In the Order model I set `$hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Product';`

on the `orders_products` table I have a couple extra fields: `order_id`, `product_id` plus `price`, `quantity` to capture the sale price and quantity sold.

I am saving the data via:

> $this->Order->saveAll($data);

Here is what $data is:

```
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => st@kr.com
            [billing_first] => Steve
            ... //more excluded
            [total] => 5000
        )

    [Product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [price] => 5000.00
                    [quantity] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

The order gets saved to the order table but nothing is getting saved to the orders_products table. I am expected the orders_products table to save `[new_order_id], 1, 5000.00, 1`

I do get this notice:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: id [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1391]

Model::__saveMulti() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1391
Model::save() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1355
Model::__save() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1778
Model::saveAll() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1673
CartsController::saveOrder() - APP/controllers/carts_controller.php, line 128
CartsController::checkout() - APP/controllers/carts_controller.php, line 172
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HABTM is over-sold. A lot of the times it fails to meet the needs, such as when you have additional data to store. You'll be better off to do a hasMany/belongsTo relationship between the models.

Taken from the CakePHP Book:

> **What to do when HABTM becomes
>   complicated?**
>
> By default when saving a
>   HasAndBelongsToMany relationship, Cake
>   will delete all rows on the join table
>   before saving new ones. For example if
>   you have a Club that has 10 Children
>   associated. You then update the Club
>   with 2 children. The Club will only
>   have 2 Children, not 12.
>
> Also note that if you want to add more
>   fields to the join (when it was
>   created or meta information) this is
>   possible with HABTM join tables, but
>   it is important to understand that you
>   have an easy option.
>
> HasAndBelongsToMany between two models
>   is in reality shorthand for three
>   models associated through both a
>   hasMany and a belongsTo association.

In your case I would suggest making a `LineItem` model and joining everything that way:

- `Order` hasMany `LineItem`
- `LineItem` belongsTo `Order`, `Product`

Comment: Thanks, it does seem to work fine if I do it that way. I called my new model `Purchase` though.

Comment: The CakePHP book has a great example of this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model

Comment: the correct way to join such the models :
Order hasMany LineItem,
Product hasMany LineItem
 LineItem belongsTo Order, Product

Comment: @ColinO'Dell 's link above is broken. Similar info here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model .

Comment: Here's an archive of the original 1.3 docs: https://web.archive.org/web/20141103144733/http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model

Answer (score 2):

Well HATBM works in an very strange way. If you really need HATBM I would suggest NOT changing a model association, but using an interesting shorthand for saving additional data fields in the join table.

I've encountered this a lot of times and this is the best solution:
Actually, just for saving your additional fields you can unbind all HATBM relations and
add a new hasMany binding "on the fly" pointing to the join model.
Firstly you should unbind the existing HATBM relation.

```
$this->Order->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Product')));
```

Then add a new "on-the-fly" hasMany binding:

```
$this->Order->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('OrdersPost')));
```

Then if your data is:

```
$this->data['Order']['id'] = '1';
$this->data['OrdersPost'][0]['product_id'] = '15';
$this->data['PostsTag'][0]['price'] = '5000.00';
$this->data['PostsTag'][0]['quantity'] = '1';
$this->data['OrdersPost'][1]['product_id'] = '16';
$this->data['PostsTag'][1]['price'] = '4000.00';
$this->data['PostsTag'][1]['quantity'] = '2';
```

As mentioned above, HATBM always erases all existing records before inserting new ones.
So maybe you should take care about that before you do:

```
$this->Order->saveAll($this->data);
```

This works when you dont want to change your datamodel, but still need additional functionality.
Hope this helps.
[Original Solution and Credits HERE](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/09/24/saving-extra-fields-in-the-join-table-for-habtm-models/)

Answer (score 1):

Another problem I usually encounter with using SaveAll is that it doesn't save the related records. In your example, the Order is saved but the OrderProducts(or OrderItems) are not saved. What I usually do is something like this:

```
if ($this->Order->save($this->data)) {
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($this->data['OrderProduct']); $i++){
        $this->data['OrderProduct'][$i]['order_id'] = $this->Order->id;
    }
    $this->Order->OrderProduct->saveAll($this->data['OrderProduct']);
}
```

What happens here is that the Order is saved first, then its ID is copied to each OrderProduct. Then OrderProduct records are saved.

Answer (score 0):

Saving that additional data in your `orders_products` table doesn't seem like a good idea to me. What if a order has more than 1 product. Do you store the total amount of the order for each entry in the `orders_products` table? Why don't you just store that information in the `Order`? That makes much more sense to me.

Your error seems to come from a broken data model.

Comment: I am storing how much the product sold for, not the order total. I can have many products tied to 1 order and it will work fine. I will have what each product sold for, then tax, total, etc. saved in the order table. If I just store a total and not what each individual item sold for, and a customer buys 3 items and then wants to return one, how will we know how much to refund them?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Going with Jason's approach seems a good idea then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous solution, BUT if have also to update the parent tables, you must unbind.
In my example I have a table *Order* and a table *Product*. I needs to put two extra fields for every product with respect to the *Order.id* . See this example:

```
    $this->Order->create(); 
    $this->Order->unBindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany'=>array('Product')));
    $f  = $this->Order->save($this->data,false);

    /* Save extra columns in HABTM TABLE */
    $this->Order->bindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('OrderProduct')));
    $q = array();
    if (!isset($this->data['Product']))
    {
        $v  = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $v =true;

        for($i=0;$i<count($this->data['Product']);$i++)
        {
            $this->data['OrderProduct'][$i]['order_id']     = $this->Order->getLastInsertID();
            $this->data['OrderProduct'][$i]['product_id']   = $this->data['Product'][$i];
            $this->data['OrderProduct'][$i]['quantity']         = $this->data['quantity'][$i];
            $this->data['OrderProduct'][$i]['state_id']         = $this->data['State'][$i];
        }
    }

    $s  = $this->Order->OrderProduct->saveAll($this->data['OrderProduct']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your orders_products table does not have it's own primary key. You will get this error unless your table looks something
like this

```
CREATE TABLE orders_products (
  id integer,
  order_id integer,
  product_id integer,
  ...
```

I only just now had this same problem. Sorry such a simple answer did not
get to you sooner.