# Cakephp save extra attribute in HABTM relation

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three Models Theme, Color and ThemeColor (that maps themes available with different colors)

Structured like:

Theme (id, name, properties, image)

Color (id, name, code, image)

ThemeColor (theme_id, color_id, preview); // eg. preview => x theme with a,b,c colors and their related image //

I have baked all these Models, Controllers and Views,

Everything is working well except I am not able to save the [preview] image in ThemeColor Model.

Its related with hasAndBelongToMany.

```
 Array
(
    [Theme] => Array
        (
            [name] => Black and blue
            [theme] => black-blue
            [description] => 
            [status] => 1
            [thumb] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Koala.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => F:\Xampp\tmp\phpEBE7.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 780831
                )

        )



    [Color] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [Preview] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test.png
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried saveAll() but that did not work. Is it possible what I am tring to achieve or I will have to just do it manually.

Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't use HABTM

The simplest way to handle has-and-belongs-to-many relations with extra attributes is to obey this rule:

> When a link table has more than 2 fields: make it a model

That means convert this relation:

```
Theme <-habtm-> Color
```

Into:

```
Theme <-hasmany- ThemeColor
ThemeColor -belongsTo-> Color
ThemeColor -belongsTo-> Theme
```

This gives you more control, and simpler code/logic. It's still possible to use a habtm relation when it suits you, and not when it doesn't.

The data structure when saving would then be:

```
array(
    'Theme' => array(...),
    'ThemeColor' => array(
        array('color_id' => x, 'preview' => y),
        ...
    )
)
```

There's more detailed notes on this [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#what-to-do-when-habtm-becomes-complicated).

Comment: There is also the  old way to do it - via bind/unbind on the fly but what @AD7six propposed is the better solution. This question was answered several times [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795615/saving-habtm-with-extra-fields) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998284/cakephp-friendship-between-users-linking-models-together).

Comment: The problem here in the view layer. If we talk about similar scenario,  `Recipe`, `Ingrdeient` and `IngredientsRecipe` which has `amount` attribute In `RecipesController` add view, How we could get a multiple selection list for Ingredients and text field to assign the attribute amount for each Ingredient in the Recipe?!

Comment: @sємsєм I suggest asking a question (hint it's not hard but you'll probably need js).