# CakePHP SaveAssociated / SaveAll ignoring fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am having an issue where CakePHP is ignoring saving a field I specify and instead creating extra records. I am using CakePHP 2.3.6.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `events_guests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `promoter_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `attended` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Heres the code

```
public function addGuest($event_id, $promoter_id = null) {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Guest->create();
                $event_data = array('event_id' => $event_id);
                $data = $this->request->data;
                $data['Event'] = $event_data;
                if($promoter_id) {
                    $data['Event']['promoter_id'] = $promoter_id;
                }
                if ($this->Guest->saveAssociated($data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The guest has been added to the guestlist'), 'flash/success');
                } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The guest could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
                }
```

Here is my data that I am trying to save:

```
Array (
  [Guest] => Array
    (
      [first_name] => Joe
      [last_name] => Schmoe
    )
  [Event] => Array
    (
       [event_id] => 1
       [promoter_id] => 2
    )
)
```

My Models follow:

```
class Guest extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Event' => array(
            'className' => 'Event',
            'joinTable' => 'events_guests',
            'foreignKey' => 'guest_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'event_id',
            'unique' => 'true',
        ), 
        'Promoter' => array(
            'className' => 'Promoter',
            'joinTable' => 'events_guests',
            'foreignKey' => 'guest_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'promoter_id',
            'unique' => 'true',
        )
    );
}
```

And

```
class Event extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Guest' => array(
            'className' => 'Guest',
            'joinTable' => 'events_guests',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'guest_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'order' => 'last_name',
        ),
        'Promoter' => array(
            'className' => 'Promoter',
            'joinTable' => 'events_promoters',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'promoter_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        )
    );
}
```

The results from this are 2 records for EventsGuests, neither with a `promoter_id`.

One record receives `event_id = 1` AS EXPECTED

Other record receives `event_id = 2`, which is actually the `promoter_id`

I have tried using a mix of `saveAssociated` and `saveAll`

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:** [Cakephp save extra attribute in HABTM relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442465/cakephp-save-extra-attribute-in-habtm-relation)

For your problem, **don't use HABTM**, because, HABTM is normally use for **connect 2 tables**.

So, if you have more than 2 fields, create a model and use it like **belongsTo and hasMany** relationships.

```
class Event extends AppModel {

  $hasMany = array(
    'EventGuest' => array(
      'className' => 'EventGuest',
      'foreignKey' => 'event_id'    
    )
  );

}

class Guest extends AppModel {

  $hasMany = array(
    'EventGuest' => array(
      'className' => 'EventGuest',
      'foreignKey' => 'guest_id'    
    )
  );

}

class Promoter extends AppModel {

  $hasMany = array(
    'EventGuest' => array(
      'className' => 'EventGuest',
      'foreignKey' => 'promoter_id'    
    )
  );

}
```

Now, your relationship model.

```
class EventGuest extends AppModel {

  $belongsTo = array(
    'Event' => array(
      'className' => 'Event',
      'foreignKey' => 'event_id'
    ),
    'Guest' => array(
      'className' => 'Guest',
      'foreignKey' => 'guest_id'
    ),
    'Promoter' => array(
      'className' => 'Promoter',
      'foreignKey' => 'promoter_id'
    )
  );

}
```

And continue use your code.

```
public function addGuest($event_id, $promoter_id = null) {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Guest->create();
    $event_data = array('event_id' => $event_id);
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $data['Event'] = $event_data;
    if($promoter_id) {
      // EDITED
      $data['Promoter']['promoter_id'] = $promoter_id;
    }

    if ($this->Guest->saveAssociated($data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The guest has been added to the guestlist'), 'flash/success');
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The guest could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If my question help you and solve you problem, don't forget to vote and mark to solved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Patrick.

That helped slightly, still a bit stuck. 

Now it still creates 2 records, but the first record has the `event_id` set with a null `promoter_id` and the second record has a null `event_id` and the correct `promoter_id`

I am still working with it, will update soon

Comment: You can edit your question and put your relationships array of models? Just curiously.

Comment: Yes, I have just added the model associations.

Still have not got this working. Thank you very much for looking at this with me!

Comment: @BryanZwicker I update my answer, see and tell me if works now. I think is the better solution.